# Mounted file system NSDirectoryEnumerator NSFileManager inconsistencies - has subfolders then doesnt? Race condition?

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems, nsfilemanager, mount-point

I have a directory watcher which uses FSEvents API on Mac OS X and also polls local or remote directories on mounted server volumes for changes. It works great, and I can make an NSSet of directory URLS which have been changed and need to be traversed. It has a callback mechanism I use to feed an array of changed URLS to whatever client.

I have a particular scenario that I cant wrap my head around thats been happening with a mounted AFP or SMB volume - which tells me I have a misapprehension about something.

1 - Directory Watcher correctly notices directory content has changed (I moved something manually), it traverses the top level directories within the watch folder and returns an array of NSURLs* that are new. In my debugging this list has *never* been inaccurate.

2 - My App, a client of the Directory Watcher then enumerates each URL in the above array. If the URL exists (which it should I enumerated it moments ago) copies it to a temp folder for processing.

Code :

Directory Watcher: https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis-Framework/blob/master/Synopsis/Synopsis/Utilities/SynopsisDirectoryWatcher.m

Client App call that sometimes fails:
https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis-Analyzer/blob/master/Synopsis/Synopsis/AppDelegate.m#L497

I've been getting issues where the directory I just was notified changed, and successfully enumerated, and can see in the Finder,  is unable to be copied because it doesnt exist by according to NSFileManager. Step 2 fails ~3 out of 4 times if, and only if, the directory is on a remotely mounted file server (Mac Mini, Mac OS 10.10, a touch out of date and slow). For local changes, I have no issues, and for many other servers ive not seen this issue *at all*.

Here's a log:

[image: Log File]

Note that the folder Watch folder is enumerated correctly, the SESSION_1 folder is found.

A copy is attempted, and NSFileManager now says SESSION_1 at the same path is not found.

The security information logging is due to HFS+ extended attributes not being copied over this version of AFP. The copy is successful 3 out of 4 times.

How can NSFileManager directory Enumerator return valid, existing folder structure, and then NSFileManager copyItemAtURL tell me URL is not valid?

- I am using the same instance of an NSFileManager ive alloc inited.
- I am a delegate of my file manager, and handle copy errors/continuation
- I have tried waiting some time between directory watcher and evoking the callback so the mounted file system can settle down.
- I have been able to check NSURL resource attributes on the folders in question prior to the copy, and am able to retrieve correct values.

  - I have tried using NSFIleCoordinate with NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges

Some questions:

Are Move operations atomic on remotely mounted file systems? Ie, if I move a directory with a ton of content from /Volumes/Mount/Parent1/child_a to /Volumes/Mount/Parent2/child_a - is the directory content ever in an inconsistent state?

Is there a way to "sync" NSFileManager to force an update?

Lower level apis I should use?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? Or tell us where to look?

Comment: Hi @Willeke - I linked above 2 GitHub links above for the directory watcher which contains the FSEvents code:

https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis-Framework/blob/master/Synopsis/Synopsis/Utilities/SynopsisDirectoryWatcher.m

and the basic directory enumerator is :

https://github.com/Synopsis/Synopsis-Analyzer/blob/master/Synopsis/Synopsis/AppDelegate.m#L497

Comment: Sorry, I missed the #L497.

Comment: No worries!

I've been looking into this more deeply and it seems like there are some known weirdnesses with NSFIleManagers lower level API, copyfile.h

http://www.openradar.me/23059163

Its unclear if I am directly affected (I dont have any symlinks), but the above ACL / XATTR issues are similar nuances.

Of course, the working API is deprecated: 

FSCopyObjectSync

I'm wondering if theres a better way to phrase the question to get an answer Im looking for?